# LINQ: How to join on only a single row with the MAX ID of the join column, and not all rows?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var results = (from l in myIEnumerable
              let MaxTable2ID = l.Table2.OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.Table2ID).FirstOrDefault().Table2ID
              select new
              {
                   ...
                   myList= l.Table2.Where(t2 => t2.Table2ID == MaxTable2ID ).SelectMany(t3 => t3.Table3).Select(t4 => t4.Table4.Code).ToList(),
                   ...
               })
```

I'm trying to get the max ID on a joined table, Table2m via navigation.  But, when we hit a record in myIEnumerable with an ID that doesn't exist in Table2, then the `let` line trows a null reference.

How do I avoid the null reference?

Or, am I even doing this right?

What I REALLY want is to only join Table2 on the greatest value of Table2ID, and ignore all the other rows that would be picked up in the join.  Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Umm... i know what a null reference is.  And in general, I know how to avoid it. My question and the one to which you linked are not even remotely the same.

Comment: Maybe the title was the problem?

Comment: What datatype is `MaxTable2ID`?

Comment: it is an INT.  In the DB, it's the primary key, auto-increment, etc

Comment: The easiest way to do this is make 2 queries one to get the max id, and then one to actually select the data

Comment: Thanks Johnny.  I thought that's what I did?  I'm sure the way i did it is not what you mean.  Perhaps you could post an example as an answer?!?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to change this:

```
let MaxTable2ID = l.Table2.OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.Table2ID).FirstOrDefault().Table2ID
```

to this:

```
let MaxTable2ID = l.Table2.OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.Table2ID).FirstOrDefault()?.QuoteRevisionID ?? 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment but I can't...

Are you sure it's the let line that's throwing the NullReferenceException?
If that were the case it'd seem that myIEnumerable is missing a Table2ID value.

If the exception is happening when you assign myList, then make sure t4.Table4 is not null before grabbing the Code property from it.

Comment: yes,  it was the let line.  VS broker there and highlighted that line in debug mode.  The problem was that myIEnumerable had records in it that were not represented in Table2, so when it hit that line, it got the null reference